# Retorno em String para Array

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou fazendo um shellscript e tenho o comando que retorna:

```
$ sqlite3 banco.db 'select code from channels'
```

00
01
02
03

Quando eu atribuo o retorno a uma variável, tudo se transforma em uma única string.

```
$ export LISTA=$(sqlite3 banco.db 'select code from channels')
$ echo $LISTA
```

00 01 02 03

Gostaria que cada número fosse o elemento de uma array, como posso transformar para que possa acesar como algo do tipo:

```
$ echo $LISTA[0]
```

00

```
$ echo $LISTA[1]
```

01

Comment: tenta desta forma valores=($(sqlite3 banco.db "select code from channels")) cnt=${#valores[@]} echo "número de variaveis no array: $cnt"

Answer (score 0):

Após colocar o conteúdo do comando dentro da variável, vc deve declarar um array:

> LISTA=$(sqlite3 banco.db 'select code from channels')
>
> echo $LISTA
>
> 00 01 02 03

Agora vc deve declarar um array com o conteúdo da variável, com um delimitador:

> IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< $LISTA
>
> echo ${array[0]}
>
> 00
>
> echo ${array[1]}
>
> 01
>
> echo ${array[2]}
>
> 02
>
> echo ${array[3]}
>
> 03

Esses `echo` são apenas exemplos, vc não precisa executa-los a menos que queira ver o conteúdo de cada posição no array.
Pronto, array declarado e iniciado.